# Why my code only return 1 row? Leetcode#626

Tags: mysql

I have used MySQL. My code is

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN mod(s.id,2)=0 THEN s.id-1
WHEN mod(s.id,2)=1 AND s.id != MAX(s.id) THEN s.id+1
END) AS id,
s.student
FROM seat s
ORDER BY id
```

It only returns one row
{"headers": ["id", "student"], "values": [[2, "Abbot"]]}

But if I delete `AND s.id != MAX(s.id)`
then I will get all rows.

I don't understand it. Is my understanding of MAX function wrong?

Comment: You can not use MAX (which is an aggregate function) that way. Regardless of that, you are missing one situation in your case (if id is odd and the largest id), which will cause id to become null. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @Lennart  I didn't add the last situation because I have met errors with current codes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an agregate function which causes the result to collapse to single row.
Possible solution:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN mod(s.id,2)=0 THEN s.id-1
WHEN mod(s.id,2)=1 AND s.id != maxid.maxid THEN s.id+1
END) AS id,
s.student
FROM seat s
join (select max(s.id) as maxId from seat) as maxId on 1=1
ORDER BY id
```

You are using it in the SELECT, not CONDITIONAL (WHERE).
Now, the question you ask is a good one and i would have to refresh my knowledge of inner workings of SQL.

I think its because the moment it hits MAX, its collapses the result set, as it doesnt "see" a need to return all rows.

Simply said, the query processor doesnt care if its a condition in case statement or value to be returned. It's there and thats that.

Aggregation function without group by is a mysql thing, and not SQL standard, so the behaviour is specific to MySQL.

Comment: Why using an agregate function in a conditional expression will cause the result to collapse?

Comment: @LangREN [If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

Comment: You can use CROSS JOIN instead of JOIN ON true.